# How to select the fcurve of a material

Tags: materials, graph-editor, dopesheet, nla-editor, fcurves

I have a fcurve assigned to a material, but for some reason it neither influences the Offset, which it should be, nor shows up in the Dope Sheet or NLA Editor. And actually, the X-Offset is only greeen because I readded a keyframe - it was somehow gone. Now what I want is to simply select the action. But it never shows up ANYWHERE...

Edit: I can select it in the NLA Editor now, but I need it to show up in the graph editor, which it doesn't, neither is it present in the Dope Sheet

[image: NLA]
[image: Graph editor]
[image: Dopesheet]

Comment: In the Dope Sheet editor choose Dope Sheet from the dropdown in the header, Action Editor is chosen in your screenshot.

Comment: still not working as it should be - see my edit

Comment: Hard to tell from screenshots as you cut them off; if animation is present in NLA editor then probably you pushed down action [from the Action Editor to NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/tracks.html#action-track)

Comment: but on the top you see the NLA Editor and AFAIK it doesn't look like this when pushed down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [action editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/action.html) that you are using only shows a subset of keyframed values, to see all available keyed data you need to use the full [dopesheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html#dope-sheet-modes) or the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html).

[image: material keyframes]

If the values you are looking for are still not visible then check the options in the header that [filter the displayed items](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#view-controls).

[image: filter options]

**EDIT:**

An action is basically a container for animation data that can be turned into an NLA strip. One active action is associated with an object for editing and is cleared when added to the NLA, it can manually be activated again in the action editor if further editing is needed. The dopesheet and graph editor only show animation data that is in the current action for an object.

A materials animation data is stored in it's own action, but this action is not shown in the action editor and only material animation data that is associated with a material in a selected object is shown in the dopesheet and graph editor. Once a materials action is turned into an NLA strip blender does't provided a simple way to re-activate it for further editing. You need to use python to re-activeate a materials action so that it can be edited.

In blender's [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html) enter the following (adjusting the names) -

```
bpy.data.materials['Material'].animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions['Material.action']
```

Then the material animation data can be edited in the dopesheet or graph editor.

Comment: ok you already helped me by pointing to that bottom bar. the mistake was that the object was not visible so the items were only visible when I enabled that ghost on the bottom - it shows up in the NLA editor now, but still not in the Dope Sheet or the graph editor - I'll edit my post

Comment: @Xerus Seems material action data is separate, see the edit.